# How to reset Form data in Multi From in react Js

Tags: reactjs, react-forms

I have created a multiForm but its not resetting the form field when I click on Reset button

Can anyone help
Below is the code ,

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import Step1 from './Step1';
import Step2 from './Step2';
import Step3 from './Step3';

const MultiStepForm = () => {


    const [test,setTest] = useState("");
    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({});

    const [clearInput, setClearInput] = useState(false);

    const clearInputsFun = () =>{
        console.log("Call");
        setTest("");
        setClearInput(true);
        setFormData({});
       
    }

  

    const updateFormData = (e) =>{
        setFormData({...formData,[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
    }

     const DisplayPage = () =>{
        if (page == 0) {
            return <Step1 formData = {formData} setFormData = {setFormData} updateFormData = {updateFormData}/>
        } else if (page == 1) {
            return <Step2 formData = {formData} setFormData = {setFormData} updateFormData = {updateFormData}/>
        } else {
            return <Step3 formData = {formData} setFormData = {setFormData} updateFormData = {updateFormData}/>
        }
     }

    return (
        <>
      
        <div>{DisplayPage()}</div>

        <input type='text' name= "test" value = {test} onChange={(e) => setTest(e.target.value)}></input>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={((e) => setPage(page-1))} disabled={page<1}>Previous</Button>

        <Button variant="primary" onClick={((e) => setPage(page+1))} disabled={page>1}>Next</Button>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={((e) => clearInputsFun())}>Clear</Button>
        </>
    )


}

export default MultiStepForm;
```

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
const Step1 = ({formData,setFormData,updateFormData}) =>{

    console.log("formData",formData);


    return(
        <>
       <Form>
      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" name= "email" value = {formData.email} onChange={(e) => updateFormData(e)} />
      </Form.Group>

      <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicPassword">
        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" name= "password" value = {formData.password} onChange={(e) => updateFormData(e)} />
      </Form.Group>
      
  
    </Form>
        </>
    )

}
export default Step1
```

import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';

const Step2 = ({formData,setFormData,updateFormData}) =>{

```
return(
    <>
    Other Info
   <Form>
  <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
    <Form.Label>Job Title</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Job Title" name= "jobTitle" value = {formData.jobTitle} onChange={(e) => updateFormData(e)} />
  </Form.Group>


  

</Form>
    </>
)
```

}
export default Step2

From should get reset when i click on reset button but when i navigation to next page then only form is resetting.